# Can't delete white space in a substring thorugh regular expression in python 3x

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, search

My string is **Some garbage 13245 65798 username@hostname.com and others garbage texts.**
I want to separate **13245 65798** , **username** and **hostname.com** through regular expression.
I use search function but i face a problem with a white space.
When i try to separates this **13245 65798** substring then a extra **white space** stay after separate.

**My code**

```
>>> m =  re.search('(\d[\s\d]+)([\w]+)@([\w.]+)','Some garbage 13245 65798 username@hostname.com and others garbage texts.')
```

**Output**

```
>>> m.groups()
('13245 65798 ', 'username', 'hostname.com')
             ^
```

Here it the extra white space.
How can i remove that space ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just `strip()` it afterwards?

Comment: `s='Some garbage 13245 65798 username@hostname.com and others garbage texts.'; re.findall('(\d+\s\d+) (\w+)@(\w+.com)', s)` is probably the cleanest regex I can think of.

Comment: The reason why you're getting that extra white space is that `[\s\d]` will match any character that is either a separator or a digit. You probably meant `(\d+\s\d+)`, or the even simpler `(\d+ \d+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m =  re.search('(\d+(?:\s*\d+)*)\s*([\w]+)@([\w.]+)','Some garbage 13245 65798 username@hostname.com and others garbage texts.')
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/14